# trouble in installation of php-devel centos 6

Tags: php, centos

I am installing `php-devel` like below

```
yum install php-devel
```

and error like below

```
Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.1-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-ftp
           Removing: php56w-common-5.6.20-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-ftp
           Obsoleted By: php-common-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
           Available: php56w-common-5.6.19-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-ftp
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.1-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-xml
           Removing: php56w-xml-5.6.20-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-xml = 5.6.20-1.w6
           Obsoleted By: php-xml-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
           Available: php56w-xml-5.6.19-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-xml = 5.6.19-1.w6
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.1-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-bz2
           Removing: php56w-common-5.6.20-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-bz2
           Obsoleted By: php-common-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
           Available: php56w-common-5.6.19-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-bz2
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.1-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-cli
           Removing: php56w-cli-5.6.20-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-cli = 5.6.20-1.w6
           Obsoleted By: php-cli-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
           Available: php56w-cli-5.6.19-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-cli = 5.6.19-1.w6
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.1-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-pcre
           Removing: php56w-common-5.6.20-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-pcre
           Obsoleted By: php-common-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
           Available: php56w-common-5.6.19-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-pcre
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.1-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-posix
           Removing: php56w-process-5.6.20-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-posix
           Obsoleted By: php-process-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
           Available: php56w-process-5.6.19-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-posix
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.1-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-tokenizer
           Removing: php56w-common-5.6.20-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-tokenizer
           Obsoleted By: php-common-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
           Available: php56w-common-5.6.19-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-tokenizer
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.1-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-zlib
           Removing: php56w-common-5.6.20-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-zlib
           Obsoleted By: php-common-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
           Available: php56w-common-5.6.19-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-zlib
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try installing EPEL 6 first,

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
yum install epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
rm -rf epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
```

after that's done, try running,

```
yum install php
```

Comment: Edited my comment @user2340312

Comment: Mixing 3rd party repo can only raise issue (webtatic + remi-php56). Try disabling webtatic, and only use "remi-php56". Also remove php56w-pear and use php-pear.

Comment: And try again php56w-pear vs php-pear issue should be fixed (after mirror close to you will be synced)

Answer (score 0):

You installed and enabled webtatic and remi repositories at the same time.
For solving this problem for install php* packages, enable one and disable the others. For example run `yum install --disablerepo=webtatic php-devel` or go to `/etc/yum.repos.d` and disable a repository by editing .repo file.